# Meaning of "man of his own invention"

Tags: meaning, idioms

There is a song "Something That I Want" (ending theme from Tangled). It has the following lines:

> She's a girl with the best intentions.
>
> He's a man of his own invention.

What is the meaning of the second line? Is there are some kind of idiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a version of the more common expression **self-made man.** It indicates a person who has made their own way in the world, most usually someone who started life poor and became rich by hard work.

Comment: I pretty much agree (+1) but would say that self-invention doesn't necessarily equate with financial wealth - at least not in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the second line as to whether it was an idiom or a phrase.
However I dint find anything of such sort.
Perhaps the line " He's a man of his invention" means that the person in question discovered some unique traits within himself and worked upon them to make himself successful.